# Finding the Lie Algebra of a Lie Group

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am having a hard time finding the set of all $X \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$ such that $e^{tX^T}Be^{tX} = B$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. where $b$ is any matrix in $M(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Where are you stuck? And what's B?

Comment: "Linear Algebra" does not usually refer to anything other than the *subject*, but here you seem to be using it to refer to an algebraic object. Do you mean the *Lie algebra* of the Lie group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Differentiate both sides of
$$e^{tX^T}Be^{tX} = B\tag{1}$$
with respect to $t$ and evaluate the derivatives at $t=0$, you get
$$X^TB+BX=0.\tag{2}$$
So, all solutions to $(1)$ must be solutions to $(2)$. Conversely, by using the power series expansion of the matrix exponential function, show that whenever $(2)$ is satisfied, $(1)$ is satisfied too. Now equation $(2)$ can be rewritten as:
$$\left[(B^T\otimes I)K+(I\otimes B)\right]\operatorname{vec}(X)=0,\tag{3}$$
where $\otimes$ denotes [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ is the [vectorisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) of $X$ and $K$ is the [commutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix). So, in principle, we can find all solutions to $(1)$ by solving the system of homogeneous linear equations $(3)$.